# Java ee: Can't create ear project in eclipse using Tomee

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, apache-tomee

I am using Tomee plus as a server for my java ee project in eclipse. I am unable to create an ear project in eclipse as the option for target runtime does not have apache tomcat for option. The only runtime environments I see are:

Basic - which has J2ee runtime library
Jboss 
Object Web

Just to clarify, I am able to create a dynamic web project with tomee runtime. The problem is creating an EAR project with tomee runtime. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to install the JST Server Adapters Extensions. I believe this was only added recently (Mars?).